# tinyMCE4 can't get external templates to work

Tags: tinymce-4

I'm very new to tinyMCE (and to JavaScript), so I'm sorry if the answer to my question is obvious. (I'm also working on code and files that another developer created and that I'm not overly familiar with.)

I need to use an external template file for tinyMCE4, and I can't get it to work. I've looked at the tinyMCE4 documentation, but I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

The tinyMCE init is in an index.cfm file, and the list of templates is in a separate file, template_list.js.

Contents of template_list.js:

```
var tinyMCETemplateList = [
 ["Name", "templates/file1.cfm", "Name."],
 ["Name2", "templates/file2.cfm", "Name2."],
...
];
```

In index.cfm, I've included "template" in the plugins line.

To pull in the templates to appear as a list in a drop-down so the user can choose a template, I've tried:

```
template_external_list_url: "tinymce/js/tinymce/template_list.js"
```

With this, when I run the program and click the Insert Template button I get a "No templates defined" error.

I've also tried:

```
templates : [{url:"tinymce/js/tinymce/template_list.js"}]
```

With this, the Insert Template dialog box appears, but the drop-down is empty, and the raw code from template_list.js appears in the text area under the drop-down. I get the same result if I change the code in template_list.js to:

```
[
 {title: "Name", url: "templates/file1.cfm", description: "Name."},
 {title: "Name2", url: "templates/file2.cfm", description: "Name2."},
...
]
```

...and also if I add quotations around "title", "url", and "description".

Again, sorry if the answer is obvious, but as a beginner I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation the TinyMCE configuration object expects you to pass an array containing one object for each template.  At a high level it would look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "template",
  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "template",
  templates: [
    {title: 'Item 1', description: 'Desc 1', content: 'My content'},
    {title: 'Item 2', description: 'Desc 2', url: 'development.html'}
  ]
});
```

You will note that the `templates` configuration option is passed an `array` of `objects` - this is what TinyMCE expects so no matter what you have to return an `array` of `objects`.

You can insert the template HTML directly (as shown in the first example above) or you can point to a URL that the browser can fetch when TinyMCE is initialized (as shown in the second example above).  There is no `template_external_list_url` configuration option so that is not working because its not valid.

If you want to externalize the templates outside the TinyMCE configuration you can place the data in a file and reference that via a URL.  For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "template",
  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "template",
  templates: "/path/to/the/file/templates.php"
});
```

The URL referenced there must return an `array` of `objects` as that is ultimately what TinyMCE is expecting.  Your example above seems to imply your external file is returning a JavaScript variable named `tinyMCETemplateList` - but that means nothing to TinyMCE so while the file may be loaded what is "returned" is not an array of JavaScript objects.

I would suggest you start by getting things to work without externalizing the templates (just make sure you get the basics working).  Then externalize the content to a separate file and make sure that the file returns an `array` of `objects`.  I would note that your example using `tinyMCETemplateList` seems to return an **array** of **arrays** which is not what TinyMCE is expecting.

Comment: Does an external template file have to be PHP? When I change my templates line item in tinymce.init to look like yours, it won't load the dialog box at all. It loads if I use "templates : [{url:"path/etc/template_list.js"}]". Being new to JavaScript, I also don't understand how I'm not returning an array of objects. When I research how to do that, the examples I see use the format of "{title: "Name", url: "templates/file1.cfm", description: "Name."}". Sorry I still don't understand.

Comment: The template URL can be any URL that returns the correct result.  The server side technology used is not relevant as long as it returns the proper JavaScript/ JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I found this really frustrating and fiddly to get working at all. Eventually what I'm doing is calling a function in another js file that returns an array that I give to the templates parameter.

```js
function GetTemplateArray()
{
    return new Array(
        {
            title: "2 Columns",
            url: "templates/template1.html",
            description: "Adds a 2 column table"
        },
        {
            title: "3 Columns",
            url: "templates/scf/template2.html",
            description: "Adds a 3 column table"
        }
    );
}
```

Then in the tinymce.init code:

```js
    tinymce.init(
    {
    ...
        templates: GetTemplateArray(),
    ...
```

Comment: I changed my code to match your example, but now my tinyMCE box (in the GUI) reverts to a plain textbox. The toolbars and buttons within it are gone. Any idea why?

Comment: I'd break it down a piece at at a time. Create the array in the js file where you have tinymce.init, eg myTemplateArray = new Array(... then templates: myTemplateArray.
Then move the array creation into a function in the same js file. etc.
If you don't get anywhere then if you could post your code.
I see you're new to js. Is the other js file referenced in your page? Maybe take a look at how you can get js debugging/console going...